# ggplot2 fill color from data values

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2, fill

I want to be able to set the ggplot fill color from values stored in the data frame. The following code is 'almost' what I am trying to do, except that instead of just using fill = MyColor, I want the code to actually use the RRGGBB hex value in the MyColor field.

```
df = data.frame(Animals = c("Dog", "Cat", "Horse", "Giraffe"), 
            Number = c(88, 11, 107, 59),
            MyColor = c("FFFFFF", "D9FFFF", "CC80FF", "FFB5B5"))

p <- ggplot(df)
p <- p + aes(x = Animals, y = Number, fill = MyColor)
p <- p + geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
print(p)
```

Thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ggplot(df, aes(Animals, Number, fill=Animals)) + geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  scale_fill_manual(values = df$MyColor)
```

[image]

Comment: I had tried scale_fill_manual but failed. I was missing fill = Animals. Thanks!!